# How to train your Mogwai?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, low-quality-posts

Yesterday, I met "Joe" on a tag I frequent, a new user with just one reputation point.

At the first encounter, everything was "ok". Their question was not high quality. But even then they got a great answer with a working snippet with the expected result.

But then they started to show a strange new behavior. Every 8 hours Joe duplicates! For now our scientists have verified 3 occurrences already.

After some research I now believe that Joe is a Mogwai, and that we may have turned it into a Gremlin. I don't think that it's their fault as they are now sitting in the corner telling themselves: "it wasn't me.. it wasn't me", and I believe that the robot will handle the question ban.

I came here looking for advice on handling a young Mogwai, because yelling at them: "Duplicate! BAD MOGWAI BAD! STOP DUPE!!", doesn't work. Ignoring a Mogwai can be hard when 4 of their posts are in the 10 most recent post on a tag.

Comment: Stop leaving rude and unconstructive comments please.

Comment: There was not mean to be rude.

Comment: _BAD MOGWAI BAD!_ Diminishes the OP in a kind of rude way IMO.

Comment: That's an exemple for the stories. It was never more that a "Stop the duplicate! Edit the Original question!". But when op ignor all demande of clarification. Already have a working snippet as answer 4 post ago. But keep reposting because he has to edit it  just a little.

Comment: Whatever you do: no spoonfeeding after midnight!

Comment: Base on what ? OP time zone ? Own time zone ?  From the scientist calculation I have made It's always midnight somewhere. Do we have to let them starve ?

Comment: My dad died in the family chimney while dressed as Santa Claus.  It was July, and he wasn't really a bright man, but this is offensive to me.

Comment: What is this mogwai thingy? *[Mogwai (Chinese culture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mogwai_%28Chinese_culture%29)*?

Comment: Are you sure you did not intend to post on *[Puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, **Gremlins** is a 1984 American comedy horror film directed by Joe Dante and released by Warner Bros. The film is about a young man who receives a strange creature called a **mogwai** as a pet. I'am a bit sad right now ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can close posts by the same author as duplicates, without there being any answers. That'll speed along a question ban as well.

If you notice a longer-running pattern of constant question replication and/or a string of low-quality questions on the same subject, feel free to flag one of the posts for moderator attention and we'll have a word with the user.

Whatever you do, do *not* use comments to tell a Mogwai how bad they are behaving; stick to our [be nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Be clear, be firm, but keep it constructive.

Example feedback could be:

> Please don't re-post your questions; our community often sees this as badgering. We'll now have to close your post as a duplicate, and multiple closed questions can lead to a question ban. If you want to draw attention to your question, see [*Getting attention for unanswered questions?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions)

Comment: I didn't realize that same-user duplicates contributed to a question ban. Can you say how many it would take to cause trouble for user?

Comment: @MikeM.: Such details are not known even to moderators. I'm not even 100% certain that *just* a duplicate closure would contribute.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured that might be kept under wraps. While we're kinda on the topic, if I may ask, as a hammer holder, if I happen upon a user who's managed to post _several_ repeats, is the proper action to go ahead and hammer all those myself, or should I be flagging for a mod?

Comment: @MikeM.: you as a community member can hammer them yourself; you are doing what we ask the community to do. If, however, there is a pattern of low-quality questions, you see they are persisting (posts were closed before, they still repeat-post, or there is a string of low-quality posts on the same subject and they are not showing signs of improving), then feel free to flag a post to let us know. What the community *can't* do is send a mod message, which is a stronger 'entry' into their record as well.

Comment: Ah, OK, good to know. I came across a newer user yesterday who'd been able to slip in the same question about half a dozen times. I went ahead and closed all but the one, and didn't think anything of it, until I read your answer here. I'm sure it was just innocent newbie behavior on their part; hope I didn't get them banned. Anyhoo, thanks for the info.

Comment: @MikeM.: well, new users that don't pay attention to how our site works and don't stop to think about what re-posting might do do need to at least receive a warning about their post quality. The user you dupe-closed several questions for, is now question banned, but only because that was by far from the first time they had quality issues with their posts. They already would have received warnings before you used your hammer.

Comment: Well, if it wasn't just innocent ignorance, then it is their own fault. I guess I was just wondering if I was in the right, there. That was the most drastic moderating I've yet done.

Answer (score 6):

Can't say for certain, but in the past we've had issues with people working on the same project inadvertently posting close to the same question because someone forgot to logout of a shared computer.

It's *much* more typical at universities than offices, but we've seen it in both settings. If you see the same person looking like they're trying to 'crowdsource' an entire project, or seemingly reiterating the same question .. [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor) strongly rules out transformative mogwai shenanigans while more strongly suggesting a shared login.

If it becomes a pattern (e.g. more than 2 or 3 times) flag for a moderator to review it. It's helpful if you include something like "might be a few users sharing one account" so the mods can get to it sooner than the rest of the stuff on the 'other flag' pile.

Comment: I didn't expect a shared account on a basic question when his notification must be pinging the answered question. I was more like Multiple personality disorder, could be the source of the problem. And was looking for a flag for "in need of a doctor intervention" !

Comment: Interesting, I had not considered the possibility of a shared account there.

Comment: I feel less worried now. As somebody else thought it could be a mogwai or a multiple personality disorder.